# go to another page html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files. One is `login.html` which is a simple html5 file with a form.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1">entre the pasword:
    <input type="password" name="code" placeholder="code" maxlength="6">
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="send" onclick="verif(document.form1.code)">
    </p>
</form>
```

Second is my javascript file with the below code:

```
function verif(inputtxt) {

    var pwd = "123456";
    if (inputtxt.value.match(pwd)) {
        window.location.href = 'Test.html';
    } else {
        alert('Code erron\351 ! ')
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now my problem is that when I enter my password, if it is **wrong** the alert message indicating an error should appear (it appears and I don't have a problem with that) and if it is **correct**, I should get redirected to the next page. The second part doesn't work for me.

Please help, I'm stuck with that for two days now..

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Be specific.

Comment: i've mentioned that the redirection doesn't work ...

Comment: if (inputtxt.value.match(pwd))
{
window.location.href = 'Test.html' ;}
the first test doesn't send me to the page i want

Comment: Does it enter the if? And did you try simply `inputtxt.value == pwd`? For the record, this is a password protection method you should NEVER use, except for studying.

Comment: put `alert('redirect');` right before `window.location.href = 'Test.html' ;}` to see if you're hitting the if block, and let us know..

Comment: asifric : i did what you told me , a box message appears written in it "redirect".. that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your button is a submit button, I think it is submitting the form after the JS is done and this could be the reason why you don't get redirected to Test.html (as form `action` attribute doesn't have any value.) Try the below code for the HTML form and check if this solves the issue.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" onsubmit="verif(document.form1.code);return false;">entre the pasword:
    <input type="password" name="code" placeholder="code" maxlength="6">
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="send">
    </p>
</form>
```

The `return false;` in the `onsubmit` attribute prevents the form's default submit action. The `verif(document.form1.code)` will be executed whenever the form is submitted (that is the submit button is clicked).

Comment: @neustre I did try it and it is working for me here. Are you getting any other errors in your console now? Is this your page's full code? Maybe there is something else that is affecting.